# Does React.JS need to be installed locally to be able to view a web application that uses the React.JS library?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am about to start a university project in which we need to build a web application, and asked my lecturer if we were allowed to use React.js for the build. He said yes as long as he didn't have to install anything locally and he was able to just download my submission and view it from his local machine.

Does anything need to be installed for him to be able to view my webapp when using React.js?
I'm relatively new to React.js so apologies if this is a stupid question!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The built application (unless you are depending on a server-side renderer such as next.js) can be deployed on any web server as it is just a collection of static files.

You are likely to find it won't run if launched from a `file:` scheme URL though.

Answer (score 1):

No.

If you are just using the react library, and write your code as:

```
 React.createElement("div", /*...*/)
```

then the code can be edited even with notepad++ and executed with every webbrowser out there.

If you however want to use React with JSX and all that syntactic sugar

```
 import * as React from "react"; // <- sugar

 class App extends React.Component { // <- newer js
   render() {
     return <div> </div>; // <- sugar
   }
}
```

you have to set up a build pipeline, that transpiles all the new features to the "old" JavaScript. In that case your teacher can "view" your source, and he can also open the compiled html, but he won't be able to make changes or verify that the output matches the written code without installing your buildpipeline (NodeJS, NPM, webpack, ...).

Answer (score 1):

No, they don't need to install anything globally. (Well, except for NPM, assuming you are using some NPM packages in your app.)
So, technically, all he needs to do is:
1- open the command line in the app directory.
2- npm i